# Postgres date issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to select records dated 1st of December 2018 from a table. 
Even though there are several records postgres is not returning any.

[image]

**Query:**

```
select * 
from dbo."Transactions" 
where "DateOfTransaction"::timestamp >=to_date('01-12-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy') 
  and "DateOfTransaction"::timestamp <=to_date('01-12-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

I also tried:

```
 select * 
 from dbo."Transactions" 
where "DateOfTransaction"::timestamp >=to_date('01-12-2018 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
  and "DateOfTransaction"::timestamp <=to_date('01-12-2018 23:59:59', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

What is the reason for this strange behavior? 
I have to give date in dd-mm-yyyy format in where condition.

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They cause much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: Are you **really** still using Postgres 9.1? That is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) - you should plan your upgrade to a supported version (e.g. Postgres 11) now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an explanation on *why* your query isn't working:

`to_date('01-12-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')` creates a **date** value (even if you specify a time part), so when you compare that with a timestamp it is as if you were comparing that with a timestamp value where the time part is set to `00:00:00`.

So your first query is essentially the same as:

```
where "DateOfTransaction" >= timestamp '2018-12-01 00:00:00'
  and "DateOfTransaction" <= timestamp '2018-12-01 00:00:00'
```

Which would only return rows that contain exactly `2018-12-01 00:00:00`

---

How to do it correctly?

You could simply cast the timestamp to a date and compare it with `=`

```
where "DateOfTransaction"::date = date '2018-12-01'
```

which would not be able to use an index on `"DateOfTransaction"`

If you need to make sure that query uses an index, you can use:

```
where "DateOfTransaction" >= DATE '2018-12-01'
  and "DateOfTransaction" < DATE '2018-12-01' + 1
```

---

Note that the cast `"DateOfTransaction"::timestamp` is useless as the column is already a `timestamp`

Comment: Why won't `where "DateOfTransaction" >= DATE '2018-12-01'
  and "DateOfTransaction" < DATE '2018-12-01'` work? Why do I need to add 1? Even though I am using >= and <=

Comment: Because in both cases the time part would be `00:00:00`  - see the condition below "this is essentially the same as" paragraph

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks a lot. 
Postgres is weird. I mean if I include time part it should consider it. Shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Arbaaz not if you request to create a `date`. Date values have no time part.  If you want to create a timestamp you have to use `to_timestamp()` or use proper ISO literals as I have done.